# inmobi Windows 8 Store App integration error

Tags: windows-store-apps, inmobi

I am trying to use inmobi ads in my windows 8.1 store app, but I'm getting some errors. I have addublex ads but error is not related to.

Error is

> [NETWORK_ERROR], Error description: [Network error occurred.]

This error video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NeogkmfMMtE&

My code is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using GoogleAnalytics.Core;
using InMobi.W8.AdSDK;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinklerId=234238

namespace HdTv
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {            
            this.InitializeComponent();
            CreateAd();
        }
        private void CreateAd()
        {
            SDKUtility.LogLevel = LogLevels.IMLogLevelDebug;
            IMAdView AdView = new IMAdView("af1b5fd03e484946a8b354442526dc43", IMAdView.INMOBI_AD_UNIT_320X50);    
            AdView.Height = 50;
            AdView.Width = 320;
```

And errors

```
HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Desperado\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Windows\HdTv\HdTv\bin\Debug\AppX\HdTv.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.UI.Xaml.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.ApplicationModel.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Diagnostics.Debug\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.Globalization.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Threading.Tasks\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Threading.Tasks.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.UI.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Desperado\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Windows\HdTv\HdTv\bin\Debug\AppX\HtmlAgilityPack.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Resources.ResourceManager\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.Foundation.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Collections\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Collections.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Desperado\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Windows\HdTv\HdTv\bin\Debug\AppX\AdDuplex.Universal.Controls.Win.XAML.winmd'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Desperado\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Windows\HdTv\HdTv\bin\Debug\AppX\AdDuplex.Universal.Win.WinRT.winmd'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Desperado\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Windows\HdTv\HdTv\bin\Debug\AppX\Microsoft.PlayerFramework.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ObjectModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.ObjectModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.Media.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Desperado\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Windows\HdTv\HdTv\bin\Debug\AppX\SM.Media.MediaPlayer.Win81.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Desperado\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Windows\HdTv\HdTv\bin\Debug\AppX\InMobiW8AdSDK.DLL'. Module was built without symbols.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.Graphics.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Threading\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Threading.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.Devices.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IO\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.IO.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.Storage.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.XDocument\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Xml.XDocument.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
2014-09-13 16:51:16,892 InMobi SDK 2.0.2 DEBUG UserAgent: [Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; WebView/2.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko]
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Text.Encoding\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Text.Encoding.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Globalization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Globalization.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.System.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.Networking.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Reflection.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Reflection\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Reflection.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Publisher device Id is: 432c48c74039caff9daa93b6feb22373 
uid_map ::{IX:"cEV5Gm93fXJhWUZ7eX1FUHJicl9bY21weUBfdHd3dHN6cHdTaURzd1ldX3J0fwZ5dWdzZQhWCAs=",WID:"BQEKUgEOUwQCBgILW1BTUAlXV1cIAVoHU1NSAQQFBgE="}
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.Security.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.ReaderWriter\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
2014-09-13 16:51:16,992 InMobi SDK 2.0.2 DEBUG Sending Ad Request [u-id-map=Oq9PqBfSvoJmITUoB7bHXqVXY3MBBz9TDaGAWX5vtTNWOAiFYpwZv9eKT4aAyfHb%2BApH03dhyjoBDdZ%2BvOtYlnJ7mZkm45OwNhWkmXHt2eDpeoPOxwgk29ojQP%2B%2BFeKAuq6lA9jypRyla7w9VHnTzuX5Z%2FrUIy16dYk6HCagHqPAmeoCSzZZkqmKdeZiH1xG1kmNLLcM9Jn0BKamwlbFVw%2Btl78n1aEASvEe5lUpiWMewzPiTzxrrKlcM%2B9nkagg&u-id-key=1281560366&u-key-ver=1&aid=AwA%2BZAMAWowIALpfBQDijQUALvoGAAEABABeYwEAhogCAI6JCQBW0g%3D%3D&d-device-screen-size=1366%2A768&d-localization=tr&d-orientation=3&u-appver=1%3A1%3A0%3A0&u-appdnm=HdTvWindows&u-appbid=45256blablabla.HdTvWindows&d-nettype=wi-fi&mk-siteid=af1b5fd03e484946a8b354442526dc43&mk-version=pr-SWPH-CTATC-20140116&mk-rel-version=pr-SWPH-CTATC-20140116&format=xhtml&mk-ads=1&h-user-agent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28Windows%20NT%206.3%3B%20WOW64%3B%20Trident%2F7.0%3B%20.NET4.0E%3B%20.NET4.0C%3B%20.NET%20CLR%203.5.30729%3B%20.NET%20CLR%202.0.50727%3B%20.NET%20CLR%203.0.30729%3B%20WebView%2F2.0%3B%20rv%3A11.0%29%20like%20Gecko&mk-ad-slot=15&u-rt=1]
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Primitives\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Primitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
2014-09-13 16:51:17,123 InMobi SDK 2.0.2 DEBUG Ad container loaded
2014-09-13 16:51:17,125 InMobi SDK 2.0.2 DEBUG Webview added to ad container
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'HdTv.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
2014-09-13 16:51:17,897 InMobi SDK 2.0.2 ERROR ErrorCode: NETWORK_ERROR, Error Desc: Network error occured.
2014-09-13 16:51:17,899 InMobi SDK 2.0.2 ERROR Error occured while processing. Error code: [NETWORK_ERROR], Error description: [Network error occured.]
2014-09-13 16:51:17,902 InMobi SDK 2.0.2 DEBUG Sent Ad Request
Ad Request failed Error Code:NETWORK_ERROR Error Description Network error occured.
The thread 0x1dcc has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1de4 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x17c0 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1d90 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x18a0 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1f80 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1a58 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0xf00 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x12b0 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1db8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[7184] HdTv.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[7184] HdTv.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

            //Subscribe for IMAdView events
            AdView.OnAdRequestFailed += AdView_AdRequestFailed;
            AdView.OnAdRequestLoaded += AdView_AdRequestLoaded;
            AdView.OnDismissAdScreen += AdView_DismissFullAdScreen;
            AdView.OnLeaveApplication += AdView_LeaveApplication;
            AdView.OnShowAdScreen += AdView_ShowFullAdScreen;

            //Set the Applcation Id            
            AdView.RefreshInterval = 20;
            AdView.AnimationType = IMAdAnimationType.SLIDE_IN_LEFT;
            IMAdRequest imAdRequest = new IMAdRequest();



            //Add the ImAdView to page
            container.Children.Add(AdView);
            AdView.LoadNewAd(imAdRequest);


        }

        void AdView_AdRequestLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Ad Loaded");

        }

        void AdView_AdRequestFailed(object sender, IMAdViewErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Ad Request failed Error Code:{0} Error Description {1}",
               e.ErrorCode, e.ErrorDescription));
        }

        void AdView_ShowFullAdScreen(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Displaying full screen");
        }

        void AdView_LeaveApplication(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Moving out of application");
        }

        void AdView_DismissFullAdScreen(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Full screen closed");
        }
```

Comment: This error may be coming due to visibility conflict for both controls. can you please share sample code how you're implementing AdDuplex with inMobi?

Comment: OK its full source:http://speedy.sh/P9WjD/HdTv.rar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that inMobi ads are shown only on tablets and not on PCs.

Most likely you are testing on your PC and you are getting NETWORK error.

Do read this :
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/d079a152-5e85-4144-b07a-f9aa2f4c1ba5/has-anyone-used-inmobi-ads-service-in-hisher-app?forum=toolsforwinapps

> "Can I get ads on Windows 8 laptops and desktops?
>
> No, InMobi serves ads only on tablets running Windows RT, and not Windows 8 Pro."
>
> "What happens if I integrate InMobi Windows RT SDK on Windows 8 Pro?
>
> The SDK will not throw any exception, but ads will not be served, and
> ad requests will fail with a network error."

Comment: Yes its my problem, i try for pc:S , thanks for answer